# Variable outputs - Html5 range slider

Tags: html, slider, range

I want to have the range slider make different calculations. Say for instance when I drag the slider to 50 its calculating at     `(0.10*this.value) , dragged to 100 it needs to be (0.08*this.value) , 200 to (0.07*this.value)` , etc. Would this be possible?

```
<input type="range" name="grade" orient="vertical min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="50" onchange="showValue(0.10*this.value) ">
    <p><span id="range">0</span>
    x 10 kg Bags of ice suggested</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue(newValue)
    {
        Math.round(7.000000000000001)
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=Math.round(newValue);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="range" name="grade" orient="vertical min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="50" onchange="showValue(this.value) ">
```

And then you can use a switch in your function    showValue() :

```
function showValue(_value) {
  switch(value) {
    case 100:
      //DO STG
      break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe Ive done something wrong, but it doesn't work properly. The code ive got now is <input type="range" name="grade" orient="vertical min="0" max="1000" value="0" step="50" onchange="showValue(this.value) ">
<p><span id="range">0</span>
x 10 kg Bags of ice suggested</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showValue(newValue)
{
 Math.round(7.000000000000001)
 document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=Math.round(newValue);
}
function showValue(_value) {
  switch(value) {
      case 50 : newValue=value*0.14;break;
     case 100 : newValue=value*2;break;
 }
}
</script>

Comment: I mean you should replace your function with mine and do your thing in it.

Comment: Here am I with a working solution, link : https://jsfiddle.net/wur9ooqs/2/ . Explanation : Chrome/Firefox have problems handling the onchange on inputs type range so you have to use `oninput` and you also have to add a default case on your switch (you'll do whatever you want), my bad on this part, hope it helped !